# Silently merge duplicate entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

Imagine a `Tag` entity that can be linked to many different objects throughout an application.

Example:

```
Tag
    name

Post
    body
    tag
```

I'm giving the ability to maintain a list of `Post` with attached `Tag`s that can be typed manually (I mean not selected from list of existing ones).

For this, I use a form with a [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html), so my tags can be converted to objects and even bound to existing in the DB.

```
public function reverseTransform($tagString)
{
    if (!$tagString) {
        return null;
    }
    $tag = $this->tagManager->getOrCreateTagFromString($tagString);

    if (null === $tag) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException();
    }

    return $tag;
}
```

My problem is, when I'm submitting a `Post` collection form linked to same new tags

```
Post1 -> "New tag 1"
Post2 -> "New tag 1"
```

My transformer gives me 2 new objects because it has no way to know we are posting duplicate ones.

```
Post1
    tag -> "New tag 1" #1234 < Different
Post2
    tag -> "New tag 1" #1235 < managed entities
```

**How could I prevent this duplication and/or silently merge the objects before the flush ?**

---

For now I'm running a "dedoublonning" function before each general persist, not ideal you guess.